# Amazon S3 delete objects with wildcard pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket and I have the following structure:

```
one/
   inside-one/
             test1/
                  abc/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                     banana/
                  def/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                  xyz/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                     banana/
             test2/
                  abc/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                  def/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                     banana/
                  xyz/
                     apple/
                     mango/
             test3/
             test4/  
                  abc/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                  def/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                  xyz/
                     apple/
                     mango/
                     banana/    
   inside-one-two/
   inside-one-three/
two/
three/
```

And I want to delete the ONLY the  `/banana` directory in each directory. So I thought of writing a `lifecycle-rule` with `prefix` limiting the scope of this rule using one or more filters

So I added the following prefix, and I think the correct prefix for this would be:

```
one/inside-one/*/*/banana
```

Can someone help me confirm that? Is my `prefix` right and it wouldn't delete anything other than following files/directories?

```
one/inside-one/test1/abc/banana
one/inside-one/test1/xyz/banana
one/inside-one/test2/def/banana
one/inside-one/test4/xyz/banana
```

Comment: I haven't tried this at all, but you may be able to try something like: `one/inside-one/**/banana`. Essentially says "look through every child of inside-one, for every banana". Not sure if AWS adopts this pattern, though.

Comment: Delete how? Using AWS CLI? Lifecycle rules? AWS SDK?

Comment: why you have used `**` one is enough right?

Comment: @Marcin using lifecycle rules

Comment: Sadly you can't do this. Wildcards are not supported in lifecycle rules.

Comment: @Marcin can I confirm this? Is there an aws documentation it says can't?

Comment: Documentations usually list what you can do, as listing things that are not supported can go forever.

Comment: @Marcin no I want to get confirmed what you said about `Wildcards are not supported in lifecycle rules`

Comment: * is a valid character as a object key name. So that's the underlying reason why this is not possible.

Comment: Is this a one-off task? If so, it would be easiest to write a script (eg in Python) that loops through ever object in the `one/inside-one/` prefix and checks whether the Key contains `/banana/` (eg `'/banana/' in key`). If so, it can delete the object.

Comment: Thank you, this is a one time task so I think the most preferable way is to write a script.

Answer (score 1):

Because the wildcard asterisk character (*) is a valid character that can be used in object key names, Amazon S3 literally interprets the asterisk as a prefix or suffix filter.

So because of above this is not possible in lifecycle-rules.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-event-notification-filter-wildcard/

I think best way on how to do is using a Lambda that checks the object key with your wildcard to delete these files. Use CloudWatch Events to trigger the lambda.

Comment: You mean, I have to write a lamba that recursively check for the correct key and delete the object?

Comment: Recursively or not just check the files in your prefix if they have the banana key and delete the file

Comment: Also depends if this is a task you only need to run one time (use a script) or is this something you need to do often (use a lambda) like John mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thank you, this is a one time task so I think the most preferable way is to write a script.